# highlight hover element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have different images on a div with a `grayscale` attribut. I'd like to colorize the pic on hover effect.
Now I can colorize all of them with the current scripts :

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="featured-block-widget"></a><a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="featured-block-widget"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="featured-block-widget"></a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container a img{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);a
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

JS (on chrome):

```
$(".container a").hover(function() {
        $(".container a img").css("-webkit-filter", "none");
    }, function() {
        $(".container a img").css("-webkit-filter", "");
    });
```

You can execute the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5shf262g/).

How to colorize only the current image?

Thanks.

Comment: Why jQuery? `.container a img:hover { ... }` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/187z353e/))

Comment: You can also change `$(".container a img")` to `$("img", this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this :-

```js
$(".container a").hover(function() {
   
     $(this).find("img").css("-webkit-filter", "none");
 }, function() {
     $(this).find("img").css("-webkit-filter", "");
 });
```

```css
.container a img{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="featured-block-widget"></a><a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="featured-block-widget"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="featured-block-widget"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't see any coloring effect.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".container a").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").css("-webkit-filter", "none");
}, function() {
    $(this).find("img").css("-webkit-filter", "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your fiddle but haven't found any coloring effect. But i think you wanted such kind of effect:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container a img").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("img_gray");
  })

  $(".container a").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").removeClass("img_gray");
  }, function() {
    $(this).find("img").addClass("img_gray");
  });
});
```

```css
.img_gray {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="featured-block-widget">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="featured-block-widget">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="featured-block-widget">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Do u need like this?

we want to see a particular image by using this keyword.It refers to current object that means your current image.
```

you can refer the link:https://jsfiddle.net/5shf262g/3/

Answer (score 0):

Define the patch and use `this` you dont need to use `.find()`

```
 $(".container a img").hover(function() {
            $(this).css("-webkit-filter", "none");
        }, function() {
           $(this).css("-webkit-filter", "");
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5shf262g/5/

and using only css

```
.container a img{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.container a img:hover{
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -moz-filter: none;
    -ms-filter: none;
    -o-filter: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5shf262g/6/